# Printing kwargs.pop displays the right value, using it in a method takes None

Tags: django, forms, keyword-argument

I ant to pass a PK in kwargs to a form :

**views.py**

```
def create_mapping_form(request, pk):
context = {
    'form': MappingForm(pk=pk)
}
return render(request, 'flows/partials/mapping_form.html', context)
```

In the form i retrieve the PK using :

**forms.py**

```
class MappingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MappingField
        fields = (
            'fl_col_number',
            'fl_col_header',
            'fl_cross_field_name',
            'fl_cross_position',
            'fl_replace_list'
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.pop('pk', 'Rien')
        super(MappingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #print(pk)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.fields['fl_replace_list'].widget.attrs[
            'placeholder'] = "Liste de tuples eg. : [('reman','ES'), ('Gasoline','Diesel')] "

        headers = GetCsvHeadersAndSamples(pk)['headers']
    [...]
```

For populating some fields' CHOICES, I use a method that returns a dic (last line above)

```
headers = GetCsvHeadersAndSamples(pk)['headers']
```

But something I can't explain sends `Rien` to `GetCsvHeadersAndSamples` while when I `print(pk)` the right value is shown. (`GetCsvHeadersAndSamples` is not useful, I don't show it).

**Note**: I display the form in template using HTMX. The issue seems not coming from HTMX because when I hard-code the PK, everything is ok.

For the moment, I have found nothing else but storing the PK value in a "temp" file but this slows down my script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I moved **GetCsvHeadersAndSamples** from **forms.py** to **views.py** and passed the return of **GetCsvHeadersAndSamples** in form kwargs.

```
      [...]
      headers_samples = GetCsvHeadersAndSamples(pk)
      fiche_headers = fetch_fiche_headers()

      form = MappingForm(request.POST or None,
                   headers_samples=headers_samples, 
                   fiche_headers=fiche_headers)
      [...]
```

Then I retrieve them in the form's **init**

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.headers_samples = kwargs.pop('headers_samples', None)
         self.fiche_headers = kwargs.pop('fiche_headers', None)
```

Issue solved with a workaround ... but still not explained